# Xcode 8 and iOS 11 incompatibility despite having copied device support files

Tags: xcode, path, compatibility, ios

I have set up up a new computer (MacBook Pro) from a backup I made yesterday from my old computer (MacBook Air). In the process of that setup, I changed my user's home folder name, strictly following the apple guide on that topic.

On my old computer, I had to move Xcode's device support files to an external disk and then manually created symbolic links between those files and the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport` directory. All of that worked, even when I installed Xcode 9 and linked its new device support files to Xcode 8 (using [this](https://gist.github.com/DreamingInBinary/cb387557c956ae7e1d2de3d42ab7b2f4) tutorial, but again symlinking instead of copying). Unfortunately, this approach does not work anymore on my new computer. On this machine, I moved all of the (before linked files) from my external Volume to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport`.

However, if I now want to run a project using Xcode 8 on my iOS 11 device (which did work on my old machine), I get the following message: `This iPhone 6s Plus is running iOS 11.0 (15A5304i), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.`

I have tried various methods, copying the needed files to both `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport` and `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`, but none of the approaches seemed to work.